# JS - moving an image horizontally after a period of time

Tags: javascript, image, settimeout

Everything was going smoothly until now. I want to have this hor() function reverse after 20 seconds. The original hor() function grabs an image offscreen and moves it horizontally from the left to the center of the page. I'd like to create a function that does the opposite after 20 seconds. The "after 20 seconds" part is giving me the most grief. If you could show me what a new function would look like or an 'else' addition to the current function that would be great. Thanks.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

var x = -500;   
var y = 100;  


function hor(val) {

if (x <= 500){
x = x + val;    
document.getElementById("pos").style.left = x + "px";
setTimeout("hor(5)", 10);
}

}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
#pos {
position: absolute;
left: -500px;
top: 100px;
z-index: 0;
}

</style>


<body onLoad="setTimeout('hor(5)',5000)">
<div id="pos"> 
<a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems there is JS error in console, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try changing the script to this:

```
// Define variables
var x = -500,
    y = 100,
    direction = 1;

// Function which moves "pos" element
function hor(val) {
  // Move by specified value multiplied by direction
  x += val * direction; 

  if(x > 500){
    x = 500;
    // Reverse direction
    direction = -1;
  } else if(x < -500){
    x = -500;
    // Reverse direction, once again
    direction = 1;
  }
  // Move element
  document.getElementById("pos").style.left = x + "px";

  // Continue loop
  setTimeout("hor("+val+")", 10);
}
```

This code will continue moving the `pos` element by the specified value until `x` greater than `500`, at which point it will switch direction, then continue until `x` reaches `-500`, and so on.

**EDIT:**

This code will fix that issue with 20 seconds (I had thought that the 500 pixel thing computed to 20 seconds, lol).

```
// Define variables
var x = -500,
    y = 100,
    direction = 1;
    firstCall = true;
    timeElapsed = 0;

// Function which moves "pos" element
function hor(val) {
  // Don't let the first call count!
  if(!firstCall)timeElapsed += 10;
  else firstCall = false;

  if(timeElapsed >= 2000){
    // Reverse direction
    direction *= -1;
    timeElapsed = 0;
  }

  // Move by specified value multiplied by direction
  x += val * direction; 

  // Move element
  document.getElementById("pos").style.left = x + "px";

  // Continue loop
  setTimeout("hor("+val+")", 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better. However, I need the function to reverse only after 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here the img is moved horizontally and after sometime it is reverted back to its original position.

```
    <script>
        var x = -500;
        var y = 100;
        var op;
        function hor(val) {
            if (x <= 500 && x>=-500) {
                x = x + val;
                document.getElementById("pos").style.left = x + "px";
                setTimeout(function(){hor(val);},10);
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){hor(5);},1000);
            setInterval(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){hor(-5);},1000);
            },2000);
        });
    </script>
```

I have changed the timings for testing purpose only, you can change it back.

Comment: @newrecruit21 if my solution is working for you, can u accept this answer ??